# Showstopper with better-biblatex+zotero?

Tags: bibtex, zotero, better-bibtex

I am using better-biblatex to access my Zotero collections of journal articles. Mostly it works fine, though duplicate keys are a bummer (the documentation for the alternate JabRef syntax based fields is not adequate).

I am writing to discuss a different, somewhat scary feature of this combination - change in item keys.

I was just writing a paper and added a citation to a journal article (call it \cite{Chen2014} for concreteness). While I was writing the conclusions, I found another article, also by a first author named Chen and added it to my Zotero collection.

Using BibDesk, I refreshed the URL that provides the bib file to check the key for the new article. It was also Chen2014. However, to my horror, the citation key to the previous article (the one I had already cited to as \cite{Chen2014}) had changed to Chen2014a!

Now, a typical user is going to have a dynamically growing library. He or she is also going to have a large static set of .tex files (those that have already been written, or the sections of a paper than have been finalized).

This "feature" above means that everytime I have to use a previously written tract of LaTeX, I cannot be certain that article keys have not changed.

If I am not messing up something, this is an utter show-stopper.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd never heard of the system but it says you can specify fixed keys https://github.com/ZotPlus/zotero-better-bibtex/wiki/Citation-Keys

Comment: Impractical when you have hundreds, if not thousands, of articles in personal library. I might as well go with the default behaviour of Zotero.

Comment: I never heard of the system either. But if it really changes existing keys you should make a bug report.

Comment: This is basically the reason why Zotero itself generates more complicated citekeys. Since Zotero doesn't store the auto-generated bibtex keys anywhere--they're re-generated on every export--short citekeys that easily result in duplicates don't work well. The easiest solution is to use something more robust, which you can do in either better-bibtex (which gives you more flexibility) or Zotero's built-in system.

Comment: Recent versions of Better BibTeX generate stable keys without having to hand-generate them. Shifting keys no longer happens, regardless of what part of your library you export.

Answer (score 9):

The Better Bib(La)Tex plugin has since been updated to make sure your bibtex keys are unique even if not explicitly forced to a unique value. The example that is given in the question will no longer occur (full disclosure: I am the author of the plugin -- problems such as these are more swiftly handled when [an issue is lodged at github](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues)).

Answer (score 2):

Better bib(la)tex is the way to go here. You can configure it to use short static keys, these are saved in the `Extra` field, the format is `bibtex: LABEL`, these are stripped off and used by the better bib(la)tex export function.

There is a menu choice to generate keys, although these are not yet made unique, perhaps this has been added recently. Once you make them unique by editing the `Extra` field they will stay static.

I have saved a search for "No bibtex label" (`Extra` `Does not contain` `bibtex:`). This makes it easy to add missing ones.

See https://github.com/ZotPlus/zotero-better-bibtex

Comment: Not practical. I have hundreds of articles in my Zotero library.

Comment: If you install biblatex, mark all of your entries and use the `add bibtex label` menu entry. This will give you a static label for all of them. Now sort on the `Extra` field and spend a few minutes to make them unique. There will not be that many duplicates.

Comment: It seems that the collision check does work if you `Generate BibTex key` for all of them at once (this time the name is right). Mark your 1000 entries, and Just Do It, this will give you static and unique keys. Adding new ones later will not give unique keys --- but the extension author is working on this, I understand.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Several of them are very informative. The last one will not work because the library is *always* growing. Say I finish up a draft of a paper with library with 6032 entries (an example). I send it off to my colleagues. I then start working on a different paper. The library grows to, say, 6150 entries. After a week, I get back an updated draft that I need to touch up on. Can I be assured that the extra 6150-6032=128 entries have not changed the keys for the articles which existed in the collection a week ago? If not, this becomes a showstopper.

Comment: New entries do not change keys for old ones. The keys do not change for an entry unless you manually mark it and choose `Generate BibTex key`. New ones do not automatically get a key, you need to mark these and `Generate BibTex key`. An added entry may get a key that collides with an existing one, because `Generate BibTex key` only checks the items you `Generate BibTex key` for _simultaneously_. You need to check this manually when adding new items. This is relatively simple: display and sort on the `Extra` field, where the keys are stored. But as I said, the add-on author is working on this.

Comment: I am sorry but that is just not true. I have seen the old entries change in several cases. I have NEVER manually done anything to define the bibtex keys. I have separately communicated with the add-on author.

Comment: I think you are seeing the effects of exporting WITHOUT ever having done `Generate BibTex key` for anything. Then, the keys can change. But if you have done a `Generate BibTex key` for the items, they will not change anymore. Anyhow, the package author says he now has a fix in place, in his git archive. Not sure this has reached release yet.

Comment: This now works for me with the 0.6.1 release of better-biblatex: Mark several items, and select `Generate BibTex key` from the roll-down menu. This generates unique stable bibtex keys for all the marked items. Very very good.

Comment: Even this is no longer required. Unique keys are generated for each entry in the background; pinned keys override auto-generated ones, but the auto-generated ones are library-wide unique regardless of which part of it you export.

Comment: Can I see the key in the browser user interface?

Comment: You can now -- there's an option in the preferences to enable it.

Comment: Right, OK (I'd need this to distinguish the different AuthorYYYYa from AuthorYYYYb). That works, thanks. I use the Extra field for other things too, but I suppose I don't need to see that in the onscreen listing. (But one could add another column instead?) Can I get a menu item with "Copy BibTeX key to Clipboard"?